# Substract one element from another in next row but different column?

Tags: r

Basically I'm looking for a diff() function that works on dataframes and that can substract one element in row n from another element in row n+1 but that is also in another column.

So, with the dataframe :

```
> df = data.frame(X=c("x1","x2","x3"), Y=c("y1","y2","y3"))
   X  Y
1 x1 y1
2 x2 y2
3 x3 y3
```

I would like to do `df$Z=df$Y-df$Z` but with a "lag" so I get :

```
> df$Z
[1] NULL y2-x1 y3-x2
```

Without using a loop of course, I've never seen such a slow thing such as this in R...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (You showed some factor columns instead of numeric values).  If the columns are numeric,

```
 df$Z <- c(NA,df$Y[-1]- df$X[-nrow(df)])
```

Or using `with`

```
 df$Z <-   with(df, c(NA,Y[-1]- X[-length(X)]))
```

#### Explanation

For the data provided

```
 df$Y[-1]  #removes the first observation
 #[1] y2 y3
 #Levels: y1 y2 y3
 df$X[-nrow(df)] #removes the last observation
 #[1] x1 x2
 #Levels: x1 x2 x3
```

so that, when we take the difference, it will be `y2-x1`, `y3-x2`

Comment: Nice I had hard time to understand the logic but basically you just remove one line in X and Y so the vectors coincide the way we want it.

Comment: @Wicelo  Yes, I should have added some explanation.  For `X`, it is the last row or element that is removed.

Answer (score 1):

Now sure why you had to make things difficult in your example by using character values but

```
c(NA, with(df, paste(tail(Y,-1), head(X,-1), sep="-")))
```

show the subtractions you want to perform. if the data were actually numeric

```
df$Z <- c(NA, with(df, tail(Y,-1) - head(X,-1)))
```

should do the trick